# PuTTy session cannot write session log

Tags: putty, logging, session, superputty

On my putty recently it stopped writing session logs and started giving this error:
Error writing session log (ASCII mode) to file: C:\Users\Documents\PUTTY\jump-01_113100.log

I do have configured PuTTy session as:
[image]

Comment: Yes it is there. I can write to that folder too.

Comment: Quite a few things this could be. Do you have space on your C: drive? Is that directory writeable? (Seems odd that it would be C:\Users\Documents instead of c:\Users\(username)\Documents). Is PuTTY running as your account?

Comment: its working now. the new destination I assigned is on my network drive as \\ILCDTL01HS9746\Users\hs9746\Documents\PUTTY and I started seeing logs. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. I had a One Drive connected which was requiring permission to go through One Drive on my PUTTY folder. I removed and reinstalled PUTTY and now started logging on my network drive. Its resolved.